account not found when requesting oauth2 token from google cloud
Status Code: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid grant: account not found"}

I am using a service account that should have token generation permissions, and I am attempting to get a token with the code below.
I have using some recycled code from other who have faced similar issues. I am using apachehttp components for web services and io.jsonwebtoken to build the JWT. I am very new to working with these libraries and java in general, so I was wondering if there are any glaring issues from a functional standpoint that I have missed.
import io.jsonwebtoken.*
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.PrivateKey
import java.util.Base64
import java.util.Base64.Decoder
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.security.interfaces.*
import java.security.KeyFactory
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec
import java.security.Key;

iss = "serviceacct@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com" // svc account email 
scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute.readonly" // A space-delimited list of the permissions that the application requests.
aud = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" // ALWAYS

def iat = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000).trunc()
// //  The time the assertion was issued, specified as seconds since 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970.
def exp = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + 1200).trunc()
//20 minutes from now // The expiration time of the assertion, specified as seconds since 00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970. This value has a maximum of 1 hour after the issued time.

//JWT Payload 
String jsonString = """{"typ":"${iss}",
                        "scope":"${scope}",
                        "aud":"${aud}",
                        "exp":"${exp}",
                        "iat":"${iat}"}""";

// Formatting key
StringBuilder pkcs8Lines = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(BASEKEY));
String line;
while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
    pkcs8Lines.append(line);
}
// Cleaning key 
String pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Lines.toString();
pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replaceAll("\\s+","");
// Decoding key
byte[] valueDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(pkcs8Pem);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(valueDecoded);
KeyFactory rsaFact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
RSAPrivateKey key = (RSAPrivateKey) rsaFact.generatePrivate(keySpec);

// Generate Token
String jwt = Jwts.builder()
        //JWT Header
    .setHeaderParam("alg","RS256")
    .setHeaderParam("typ","JWT")
    .setPayload(jsonString)
    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, key)
    .compact();

def httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
def httpPost = new HttpPost(aud)
String bodystring = "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion="+"${jwt}"
String encodedParams = URLEncoder.encode(bodystring, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Encode
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(bodystring)

httpPost.setEntity(entity);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

def response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)

//debug
String statusCode = response.getStatusLine() //.getStatusCode();
String content = response.getEntity().getContent().getText() //.getStatusCode();
System.out.println("Status Code: " + statusCode);
System.out.println("Response: " + content);

I tried cleaning up the JWT payload to match with the documentation provided by google for their oauth2 service account authentication but it didnt help.
Something I find concerning a likely to be a problem is that I cannot get the encoding set to url-form-encoded. when I debug with
System.out.println(entity.getContentType()); it shows Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1, even though I am setting the content type of the post to url encoded. I was able to figure out how to set the content type of the entity to url encoded but my error is persisting,

Solved:
After all the frustration, it was a simple variable typo in the json object. I had entered "typ" instead of "iss" in the jsonString.
If you add your own values for iss, and scope, and import a private key as BASEKEY, this code should work.
